# Capturing the error message downloading file with nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js

I am download a file from nodejs.

When there is an error in backend, I need to send a message to front end.

My problem is that I am unable to capture that message.

I know there is some problem related to use blob and json, on back end.

But I didn´t solve it.

My code in line:

```
console.log(error.response.data.message)
```

allways returns "undefined"

```
//front end
    try{
        let response = await axios.post('/generateLoteXMLZIPConsulta');
        let blob = await new Blob([response.data], {
          type: "application/zip",
        });
        const link = document.createElement("a");
        link.style.display = "none";
        link.href = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
        const fileName = response.headers["content-disposition"].match(
          /filename=(.*)/
        )[1];
        link.download = fileName;
        link.click();
        window.URL.revokeObjectURL(link.href);
    }catch(error){
      console.log(error.response.data.message)
    }
         //backend nodejs
         router.post("/generateLoteXMLZIPConsulta", async (req, res) => {
            ....
            ....
            try
               res.download(
                    path.resolve(__dirname, "../../file.zip"),
                    "xmlFile.zip"
            );
            catch (error){
               res.removeHeader("Content-disposition");
               res.status(400).json({ message: "You got an error" });
            }
        })
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, there are a few mistakes in your code:

```js
...
  try {
    // you have to tell axios how to handle response with `responseType`
    let response = await axios.post('/generateLoteXMLZIPConsulta');

    // no need to use await here
    let blob = await new Blob([response.data], {
      type: "application/zip",
    });

    const link = document.createElement("a");

    // no need since you didn't append this element into DOM
    link.style.display = "none";

    link.href = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
    const fileName = response.headers["content-disposition"].match(
      /filename=(.*)/
    )[1];
    link.download = fileName;
    link.click();
    window.URL.revokeObjectURL(link.href);
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error.response.data.message)
  }
...
```

This is my reproduce code:

```js
// backend

app.post('/foo', async (req, res) => {
  try {
    // throw 'Something went wrong'
    res.download(path.resolve('bar.zip'))
  } catch {
    res.status(400).json({ message: 'You got an error' })
  }
})
```

```js
// frontend

;(async function () {
  try {
    // with blob response you have no need to wrap response data to create blob again
    // {} is required otherwise axios will treat { responseType } as data
    let response = await axios.post('/foo', {}, { responseType: 'blob' })
    let blob = response.data
    console.log(window.URL.createObjectURL(blob))
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error.response.data)
  }
})()
```

This is working so far except when backend throw an error, axios will treat the response as blob as we set. So we have to convert it back to json.

```js
axios.interceptors.response.use(null, async error => {
  if (error.response.request.responseType === 'blob') {
    // you may need to add an error handler if the response is not JSON
    error.response.data = await new Promise(resolve => {
      let reader = new FileReader()
      reader.addEventListener('load', () => {
        resolve(JSON.parse(reader.result))
      })
      reader.readAsText(error.response.data)
    })
  }
  throw error
});
```

This is related Github [issue](https://github.com/axios/axios/issues/815).

Comment: Thank you. Now I see my question was not trivial. It solved my problem.